# Flutter: set AnimatedList animation duration

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there a way to set the duration of the animation in an AnimatedList?

```dart
  AnimatedList(
        key: _animList,
        initialItemCount: _myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          // duration = Duration(seconds: 1); <--- ????????
          return SlideTransition(
              position: animation.drive(
                  Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
                      .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.bounceIn))),
              child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100));
        });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So...after a short research, I realized that you can only set **Duration** when you want to insert into the list or delete from the List and this is achieved by creating a **GlobalKey** of **AnimatedListState**...

I wrote an example code for inserting

```
class Pool extends StatelessWidget {
  final keys = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  var list = List.generate(3, (i) => "Hello $i");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AnimatedList(
          key: keys,
          initialItemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
            return SlideTransition(
              position: animation.drive(
                  Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
                      .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease))),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(list[index]),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          list.insert(0, "NothingYay");
          keys.currentState.insertItem(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: In the [AnimatedList official example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html), add this duration to the line `_animatedList!.insertItem(index)`.